# When the initialization of static member variable take place

Tags: c++

I have a code,

```
// CFoo.h
class CFoo
{
public:
   CFoo();
   ~CFoo();
   static const std::string mStr;
};

// CFoo.cpp
const std::string mStr = "MyFoo";

CFoo::CFoo()
{
}

CFoo::~CFoo()
{
}
```

When is my static mStr will be initialize? When my application execute? Or when creating an instance of CFoo?

Thanks!

Comment: Sometime before `main()` is called.

Comment: Also, there are many things on this topic if you search.

Answer (score 2):

It's implementation defined.

The only thing that's guaranteed is that it will be initialized by the time your application first enters the translation unit that defines it.

Comment: Also, for objects defined in same TU the order of initializations is guaranteed it is the order of their definitions.